# How to rewrite the following SQL query so that it works with HSQLDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, hsqldb

I have a table "summary" where I want to keep some summary numbers by id from
another table "foo". This is the update query that uses UPDATE FROM that seems to
work

```
UPDATE summary
SET    sum1 = t.sizes,
       sum2 = t.counts
FROM   (SELECT id,
               sum(size)  AS sizes,
               sum(count) AS counts
        FROM   foo
        WHERE  id IN (SELECT id
                      FROM   summary)
        GROUP  BY id) t
WHERE  t.id = summary.id;
```

This query works with Postgresql, but fails in HSQL as UPDATE FROM is not standard SQL.

Question, how to rewrite this query in standard SQL?

PS: It could be "standard SQL". So to be more specific. When I execute this query in HSQLDB I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: T.SIZES
```

So may be what I really need - how to get this query to work with HSQLDB.

Comment: There is not a convenient way to rewrite this.

Comment: The ANSI standard is awkward for complicated updates. Practically no one implements it exactly, every DB implements it a little different, and none of their representatives to the standards body can agree on what it should be (or are unwilling compromise their own existing syntax) to fix the situation.

Comment: It's standard SQL - There is no UPDATE FROM in the sql

Comment: I am curious: Is this or is this not the way the standard defines this? I thought they would use updatable queries ( `update (<some query>) set some_col = some_value` ).

Comment: HSQL throws this exception : ```Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: T.SIZES``` . May be the issue is not with UPDATE/FROM by with referencing  T.

Comment: That message has nothing to do with syntax. It's about permissions.

Comment: @VicInvesta absolutely **NO** database implements the standard beyond basic level support. None. And definitely not HSQLDB. *All* databases have their own proprietary syntax with extra features. The standardization process is far too slow, and the outcome the result of negotiations (read bartering) between vendors *years* if not *decades* after specific features are implemented. And several "standard" features never get widespread support, or become irrelevant, like SQLJ. Which was ratified 10 years *after* "Java everywhere" went out of fashion.

Comment: @Dri372 this means very little, if anything. No database supports the SQL standard beyond a basic level. `ORDER BY` in queries was legalized in 2008. What did databases do in the previous 20 years? Use `ORDER BY` of course. `UPDATE FROM` is just another feature everyone has that's not part of the standard probably because of bickering and companies trying to push their own syntax quirks

Comment: @Dri372 at one point teams inside IBM clashed because one product team wanted to force `value = column` as mandatory for comparisons, ie `3 = columnA` because that made the parser implementation easier. The SQL team wasn't thrilled

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you are right, but that does not mean I am wrong :-) Do you thing it's not SQL standard?

Comment: @Dri372 given that the standard isn't freely available ? I don't know. And the drafts that circulate are that - drafts. They didn't survive the final round of bartering

Comment: I am afraid this has started SQL standards discussion (and associated woes of different DB vendors not being able to agree). I modified the title of this question. If somebody has an insight on how to get this query to run in HSQLDB  - much appreciated.

Comment: @VicInvesta Clever decision :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I can't find that construction in the SQL-2016 specification.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_compliance describes a number of products complaince to Core ANSI-SQL, i.e. the mandatory  functionality. It's too bad a bunch of vendors just don't care to implement basic syntax for functionality they already have their own, proprietary version of.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite it as a MERGE statement, but not as an UPDATE statement:

```
MERGE INTO summary
USING (SELECT
               id,
               SUM(size)  AS sizes,
               SUM(count) AS counts
        FROM   foo GROUP BY id)  AS T(id, sizes, counts)
ON t.id = summary.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET sum1 = t.sizes, sum2 = t.counts
```